# Pass JavaScript variable to Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

How would I go about changing the value of a Swift variable based on a JavaScript variable? (Passing a JavaScript variable to Swift)

My goal is simply to conduct an if statement using a JavaScript variable, and than edit the swift variable based on that.

Example in code of what I am trying to do:

```
var checkElement = false
webView.evaluateJavaScript("var element = document.getElementById(\"element\");"){ (value, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
}
if (element != null){
checkElement = true
}
```

I understand this won't work due to element only existing in JavaScript. Although, how would I pass the element variable to Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I would answer this myself.

First, ensure your class is conforming to the correct protocols: `WKScriptMessageHandler` is required and you may also need `WKNavigationDelegate`.

Before initializing your WKWebView add a userContentController to its configuration. This is what will act as a 'bridge' from your JavaScript to Swift.

```
var webView = WKWebView()
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "messageName")
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

Now initialize the `userContentController()` function and handle the received content within it. Ex.

```
public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("Name: \(message.name)")
    print("Body: \(message.body as! String)")
}
```

Now within the JavaScript inside your `evaluateJavaScript()` add the following line to push whatever data to Swift:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers['messageName'].postMessage('Message Body!');
```

Now, when that JavaScript line is called Swift will output the following:

```
Name: messageName
Body: Message Body!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get variable in Swift code by interception clicked URL via `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

Simulate click you can via `iframe` in JS.

Here is an example in Objective-C, but it will be same on Swift - 
http://iwearshorts.com/blog/how-to-call-uiwebview-from-javascript/